# In document based mac app, how to get the temp folder for the untitled document?

Tags: macos, cocoa

So if in the app's delegate, I have code

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    return YES;
}
```

So when the app launches, it will create a default document file with untitled name.

My question is: BEFORE the file is saved by user (at this time a new location will be chosen), is there a way to know the path of the document at that time? (should be somewhere in the system temp folder)

Notes: Please do not ask me why I need to know the path, it is a very old project and for historic reason I need it and that cannot be changed.

Comment: How about `autosavedContentsFileURL`? It isn't difficult to find this in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but no, my App does not opt in for autoSave. That property is always nil.

Comment: An unsaved document doesn't have a path. It doesn't exists on disk. Maybe the old project does save the document somewhere but we can't know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the folder for unsaved documents from NSFileManager.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSAutosavedInformationDirectory
                                                    inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                           appropriateForURL:nil
                                                      create:YES
                                                       error:&error];
```

The path you can get via this method is the following (or nested in the Containers if the app is Sandboxed):

```
~/Library/Autosave Information/
```

Even when you don't enable autosavesInPlace feature of document-based app, this folder may be used for window resuming and so on.

But as Willeke already pointed out, an unsaved document actually doesn't have a path.

Comment: Four years later: My (non-sandboxed) app is producing an error in console and failing Gatekeeper, because it doesn't have access to read and write the `Autosave Information` folder. `autosavesInPlace` is off. Happens for both saved and non-saved files. Would you happen to know where to start digging into this problem?